# Jquery date picker, display dd MMM, whilst storing dd/mm/yyyy in data attribute

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

```
$("input.datepicker, input.date-picker").datepicker({
      format: 'dd/mm/yyyy', 
      orientation : 'left', 
      todayHighlight : true, 
      autoClose: true, 
      clearBtn: true
}).on('changeDate', function (ev) {
      $(this).datepicker('hide');
});
```

I am using the bootstrap datepicker 1.4.0, and Im trying to figure out how to do the following.

1. Allow the user to select the date via the date picker.
2. When the date is selected, display the date as dd MMM (01 March)
3. Then to store the value of the date in the data-val attribute as dd/mm/yyyy so I can pass it to the server to be stored
   in the data base via an ajax request.

the ajax part is pretty easy, but I cant figure out how to display the value in the input nicely, and store the full date in an 
additional attribute when the user chooses to change the date. Any ideas greatly appreciated

https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Simple as this:

```
$("input.datepicker, input.date-picker").datepicker({
      format: 'dd MM', 
      orientation : 'left', 
      todayHighlight : true, 
      autoClose: true, 
      clearBtn: true
}).on('changeDate', function (ev) {
      $(this).datepicker('hide');
      var date=ev.date.getDate() + "/" + ev.date.getMonth()+"/"+ev.date.getFullYear();
      $(this).attr('data-val',date);
      alert($(this).attr('data-val')); //just for demo purpose
});
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/eknw6pgy/1/)**

- **Allow the user to select the date via the date picker.**

> The below part initializes the datepicker for an input with classname `datepicker` and `date-picker`

```
$("input.datepicker, input.date-picker").datepicker({
          format: 'dd MM', 
          orientation : 'left', 
          todayHighlight : true, 
          autoClose: true, 
          clearBtn: true
})
```

- **When the date is selected, display the date as dd MMM (01 March)**

> This below event `changeDate` takes care of the displaying and storing
>   the value

```
.on('changeDate', function (ev) {
          $(this).datepicker('hide');
          var date=ev.date.getDate() + "/" + ev.date.getMonth()+"/"+ev.date.getFullYear();
          $(this).attr('data-val',date);
          alert($(this).attr('data-val')); //you can remove this
});
```

- **Then to store the value of the date in the data-val attribute as
  dd/mm/yyyy so I can pass it to the server to be stored in the data
  base via an ajax request.**

> The below part helps you to achieve the above requirement

```
var date=ev.date.getDate() + "/" +ev.date.getMonth()+"/"+ev.date.getFullYear();
//parameter passed to the changeDate event will have a property called `date` which 
//holds current date value from which you can extract the required date, month and year 
//and store it 
$(this).attr('data-val',date); // or $(this).data('val',date);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {
  $('#thedate').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd MM',
    altField: '#altdate',
    altFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
Shown Field :
<input id="thedate" type="text" />
<br />Hidden Field :
<input id="altdate" type="text" />
<br />
<input id="thesubmit" type="button" value="Submit" />
```

Check this out change the formats to your liking and boom!

Answer (score 0):

see

```js
$("input.datepicker, input.date-picker").datepicker({
  format: 'dd MM',
  orientation: 'left',
  todayHighlight: true,
  autoClose: true,
  clearBtn: true
}).on('changeDate', function(ev) {
  var $this = $(this),
    format;
  $this.datepicker('hide');
  var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
  if (date) {
    format = $.fn.datepicker.DPGlobal.formatDate(date, 'dd/mm/yyyy', $(this).data('datepicker').o.language);
  } else {
    format = '';
  }
  $(this).attr('data-val', format);
  snippet.log('selected date:' + format)
});
```

```html
<!--Only for demo-->
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>

<input class="datepicker" />
```